# Is there an URL that will let me create a Google Doc for a specific Google account I'm signed into?

Tags: google-docs, google-account, url

I have a **Personal** and **Work** account with Google. I use Google Docs to take notes, but every time I want to create a new document for work, it requires me to switch accounts. Gmail lets you access different inboxes by using different URLs. Is there anything like this for creating new docs?

Answer (score 2):

On most Google websites (e.g. Google Docs, Google Drive, GMail...), there is a Query String (details on how to load the web page) that is usually `authoriser=x` or a number between two slashes (Like this: `/0/`.
[image: Google Docs]
The authoriser query string here is the `0` between the two slashes. When you open a new google website tab, the authoriser query string defaults to `0`. 
Now, if you change your google account to (for example) the second one in the list, the authoriser query string would than change to `1` (because computers usually start counting from `0`).
However, there are some **exceptions**:

- Google Groups (Well, actually it shows up before the page loads but the page is redirected so you can't see it in the URL)
- Google AdSense (Advertisement for Google services)
- Google Product Forums (Google help)
- There might be more that I don't know off but these are just examples.

---

Now, back to your question, if your **Personal** account is the default google account, the authoriser query string would than be `0` but if your using your **Work** account (assuming it's not the default account), it's authoriser query string would be `1`.
Therefore, if the authoriser query string in your bookmark is set to `0` (The link should look like this: [www.docs.google.com/document/u/0/](http://www.docs.google.com/document/u/0/), it would automatically open up your **Personal** account but if it's equal to `1` ([www.docs.google.com/document/u/1/](https://www.docs.google.com/document/u/1/)), it would open up your **Work** account.