# A keyboard shortcut to create a blank document from the docs.google.com/document/u/0 webpage

Tags: google-docs, keyboard-shortcuts

I have gone through the [Keyboard Shortcuts for Google Docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/179738) page — didn't find what I was looking for there — and have added the AutoControl Shortcut Manager extension to Chrome.
After a brief review of its framework, it appears to me that I will have to write a script that would execute the action of creating a new blank document.
Before I begin this process, I thought I would check if there is anything I have overlooked.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to create a blank document from the docs.google.com/document/u/0 webpage?

I searched the website and couldn't find anything specifically about creating a blank document.

Comment: Related [Is there an URL that will let me create a Google Doc for a specific Google account I'm signed into?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/111138/88163)

Comment: @Rubén How could the link you provide ever be related when **the OP is clearly asking** for *"a keyboard shortcut to create a blank document from the docs.google.com/document/u/0 webpage"*?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in an [earlier comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/150606/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-create-a-blank-document-from-the-docs-google-com?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment137278_150606) there is no such shortcut by default.
Having said that and reading [your answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/150607/117311): *"I can create a new document by typing docs.new in the address bar"*, I believe you will be happier with the following.

### How to build a custom shortcut for creating a new Google file

**Steps for Google Chrome** *(a very popular browser)*

1. Go to `chrome://settings/searchEngines`
2. Click on the `ADD` button
3. On the pop-up window fill in the field for `Search engine` *(give it a friendly name that makes sense to you)*
4. For `Keyword` *(choose any combination you want for your "shortcut". I chose `=nd`)*
5. and finally **fill in the URL** `https://docs.google.com/document/create`

Now **every time you type** in your browser's address bar **`=nd`** and hit <kbd>`ENTER`</kbd> a new Google Document will be created in your root Drive folder.

[image: How to create a custom shortcut for a new Google file]

#### **Pro Notes**

You can follow the above steps and also build **custom  shortcuts for Google Sheets, Forms, Slides**

You can take it to the next level and even **create your personal, customized "Templates"** *(as described in [this post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/145753/117311))* **and build shortcuts for those** as well.
I have one (as shown in the bottom of my image) as `=intd` that I use for my invoices, with a URL like:

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/xxxxxx/copy?&copyCollaborators=false&copyComments=false&title=MY_NEW_INVOICE&copyDestination=zzzzzz
```

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well. You can even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) the answer. If you don't have enough reputation, your upvote will show up later, once you reach [enough reputation points](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Answer (score -1):

I can create a new document by typing docs.new in the address bar. More information: [the Google source.](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308871?hl=en)

Comment: Typing in the address bar isn't a keyboard shortcut. By the other hand this was already posted as an answer to [URL to create a new Google document](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/26304/88163)